# How to read xml file in selenium driver

Tags: java, xml, selenium-webdriver

I would like to read this xml with Selenium

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <client name="eLife"> <site>qa.elife.dev.cms30.kriyadocs.com/welcome</site>; 
        <xpath> 
           <publication> </publication> 
           <Article>in progress</Article> 
           <Striking>Image></Striking> 
           <Upload>Digest</Upload> <Upload>sub article</Upload> 
           <Detailed></Detailed> 
        </xpath> 
    </client>
```

Code Snippet:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/administrator/Downloads/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String URL = "http://localhost/config.xml";
String course = driver.findElement(((WebElement) By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass-nodes-list']/li/div[2]/a")).getText());
```

Comment: Your questions is not clear. do you want to read any xml file through java code or through selenium after loading the xml file in the browser?

Comment: Yes I want read XML file in Java code Through selenium

Comment: post the xml file for reference.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<client name="eLife">
 <site>http://qa.elife.dev.cms30.kriyadocs.com/welcome</site>
 
 <xpath>
  <publication> </publication>
  <Article>in progress</Article>
  <Striking>Image></Striking>
  <Upload>Digest</Upload>
  <Upload>sub article</Upload>
  <Detailed></Detailed>
   
  
 
 </xpath>
</client>

Comment: Why not use Java XML Parser instead of Selenium? Selenium has been designed to traverse HTML documents and much more. Is there a special feature you want to use?

Comment: No , I want configure our project so I will connect the xml data to selenium

Comment: I'm not inspecting the xpath here at all so I don't know if it's correct, but it seems like the above _could_ work.  Is it that selenium can't inspect the XML file because it's not HTML?  If Selenium doesn't have the ability to traverse the XML can it at least return the whole file (versus downloading it)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Load and parse the XML with the XML parser. After you get the data you want from XML, pass it to Selenium. Use the right tool for the job and you will get better results.

Comment: Okay , please update the correct code for this project

Comment: That's a completely different question from what you asked above and it has been asked before. You will want to read some Java/XMLReader tutorials to get what you need. If you do that and run into an issue, post a new question with the specifics of the issue.